# Ubuntu phone, how to get an underscore on keyboard

Tags: keyboard, phone

I cannot get the Ubuntu Phone on-screen keyboard to produce an underscore character. Long-pressing - gives me an m-dash and a dot, but no underscore. Is underscore hidden on some other key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the <kbd>?123</kbd> button to get the numeric keys and symbols.
Now a <kbd>1/2</kbd> button appears. Look at the minus-key. When clicking the <kbd>1/2</kbd> button, the minus-key becomes an underscore-key:

[image]